# Managing multiple BrowserRouters in react-dom-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-villani-s7utz?file=/src/Problem.js

**Background:**
I am attempting to write an application similar to Leetcode, where the home page is a table of coding problems and clicking on one of those problems navigates to a page to read the problem description, submit a solution and receive a result. Currently, the app has three BrowserRouters: for the App.js (nav bar), the Home.js page, and the actual Problem.js (to move between description, submission, and result).

**Issue:**
If a user navigates to a problem (click on "Add Two Numbers" from Home page), they cannot return to Home (to see the problem table) by clicking the Home button. I'm guessing it's an issue with how I'm nesting, but I'm having a hard time pinpointing the issue.

Comment: Why are you using separate Routers in the first place? I am not sure how this "approach" even works. To be honest, I didn't even know you can nest routers like that. I can see a possible use case for it, but I don't think your case qualifies for such thing. Use a single `BrowserRouter` instance that wraps the whole application(or atleast the route related tree) and you'll save yourself a lot of problems

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one Router component to wrap **all** your application. Then, inside different parts you will be able to use Switch, Route, Link and so on. They will connect to your router automatically. Routes don't have to be at the top of the application. It is enough that they are somewhere inside the tree that is wrapped.

Here is fixed code: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-pine-rq43z?file=/src/Problem.js

I replaced `<BrowserRouter>` with `<>`, except for one in the App at the top level.

Comment: I see. However, now the component doesn't show up when I go to /problem/Add Two Numbers. Can you explain why that's occuring?

Comment: Because you are rendering it inside Home and home renders on exact match with '/'

Comment: I just figured it out, wow there's a lot I didn't know about routing. Thank you so much!